# Ubuntu ignores eth0

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I am having a very frustrating problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and my network interface.

First of all the ethernet card works: the computer is dualbooted with Windows and Windows connects perfectly to the internet. So no hardware and no cable problem.

In fact as soon as I power up the computer the leds on the ethernet card start blinking...but as soon as I boot up Ubuntu they shut down!

The OS complains about a "cable not plugged in" problem, but the situation is much worse.

The `eth0` interface is recognized by `ifconfig`, but it is NOT listed under `/etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo ifup eth0` complains about "unknown interface eth0"

Nmcli reports the interface as "unavailable" and `dmesg | grep eth0` states that "link is not ready".

I have perused multiple forum entries, but nothing seems to work...any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: can you identify your hardware, from windows if necessary

Comment: can you post the output of `sudo ethtool eth0` please?

Comment: Please don't add "solved" etc. to the title. Marking an answer as accepted is enough (though it will take a short while for you to be able to do that because it is self-answered).

Comment: I can't mark my answer as accepted until tomorrow, so in the meantime, to help any other poor soul wandering the web looking for answers I'm editing the title to let them know that on this webpage there is a shining ray of hope. Any objections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of breaking my face on the Internet I finally found out that the problem was related to the god-damned Realtek 8619 (or something like that) drivers that were probably installed in one of the latest updates.
I patched it with a workaround by adding:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off
```

to `/etc/rc.local`

Now it works, even if it would probably be better to rollback to another driver as suggested elsewhere.